# place two divs next to each other with css table

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I would like to place two divs next to each other. The right div's width is determined by it's content and should be aligned to the right of the container div. The left div's width should span the rest of the page.

I managed to do this with the following code (a minimized version of the original obviously):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: table;
            width: 1000px;
        }

        #left {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #right {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        #image {
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left">
            blabla
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="image">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Works perfectly in both chrome and firefox, but in IE, the #right div is shown below the left one.

The idea is that only the #container and the #image have dimensions that are explicitly set. All other dimensions should be inferred from those by clever aligning somehow. The display: table-cell css property accomplishes this nicely, but nothing else seems to do...

Does anyone know a solution? There are a lot of "place div's next to each other" questions already, but all solutions seem to depend on all div's having fixed widths..

Answer (score 4):

#### Change the CSS this way:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Let us know if you find some issues in this!

Comment: The image does not fill the #right div. Also, it requires multiple width's to be set which is annoying. I just want to set the page width (in this case the #container div) which applies to every page of the website regardless it's contents. The width distribution of the #left and #right divs should be completely determined by the content width of the #right div. I will edit my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the

```
#left{width:600px;float:left};
#right{width:400px;float:left};
```

your problem solved.

Comment: I whole point was that I wanted the width: 600px to be inferred from the other dimensions. I realize that I did not make this very clear. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

look this one. it works.

```
 <html>
<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: table;
            width: 1000px;
            float:left;
        }

        #left {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 57%;
            float: left;
        }
        #right {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: top;            
            float: right;
        }
        #image {
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left">
            blabla
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="image">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This requires a width property to be set in three different places. I don't want the width's to be 50%. I just want the image to have a width of 400px and height of 300px. All the other dimensions should be inferred from that.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have IE in my mac. As per i understand write like this:

```
#container {
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: table;
            width: 1000px;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }

        #left,#right {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: top;
            white-space:normal;
        }
        #image {
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the right div is not aligned to the right, but is place next to the left one.

Comment: I didn't really make it clear that that was mandatory, sorry. I edited my question accordingly.